# Choosing which hypothesis test to use?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm sitting a statistics exam this week, and I'm having trouble recognising which test to use?
We get told either 
a) use a parametric test or
b) use a non-parametric test

but is there a method to choosing the right one?
I've split them into two sampled and one sample but for example then I get confused with the standard deviation with the 'z' or 't' test?

Can anyone offer any advice? (Or even a flow chart for choosing tests would be great! - I joke)

Thank you!

Comment: Technically speaking the $z$- and $t$-tests are both parametric tests because they assume the underlying data are drawn from a Normal distribution...

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by that, is how do I know when to use the '$z$' test or the '$t$' test when it is only one set of data?

Comment: If the sample size is small (less than 30 or so) and you are NOT told that the variable is normally distributed then use a t test. Otherwise, use a z-test. More or less. If you do a nice well laid out solution your examiner will be delighted and won't be too bothered which you use I bet!

Comment: Another thing you might want to look at is the wording of the problem. If the given standard deviation is said to be the population-standard deviation, and the underlying model is assumed to be normal, then you can use the z-test. But if it is given that the standard deviation is a figure derived from your sample, then stick with the t-test. Honestly, there is some grey area here and it depends on the professor teaching it what is allowed. If you use proper argument about which one you choose, I tend to agree with Paul's comment

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Thank you very much! I'll make sure to write a clear solution and why I chose that test!